# Is it possible to do things at an OS level when designing an iOS app like stopping the user from using other apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, security

Could I use the frameworks provided by Apple and be within their terms of service and make an app that stops users from using specified other apps that they personally specify as not wanting themselves to use?

Edit: ideally this would stop them from using the other apps at all times, not just when they have the app that blocks them from doing it open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. iOS apps cannot affect other apps or block them from running.

There is a "kiosk mode" that you can put an iOS device into that prevents switching apps, but it requires that the user set it up, and it locks the device to just that app.